# Why does "summarize count()" on a stored query result always give 0?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

The following creates a [stored query result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results) named "tmp" with 100 rows from **StormEvents**:

[Run query](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/https%3a%2f%2fhelp.kusto.windows.net/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAEABXMQQqDMBhE4avM0oKI7nUhpSfoAaTgiMGq6Z9JVPDw1e3j4xWBQtBq7LtfpB2dMcSvoNljcxqReWNy3J5rXIQGVQ7u3l2sHUS7y%2fhAfeJ9XeZX4qKAE%2fpMRFWWf9TCHiFhAAAA)

```
.set stored_query_result tmp with (previewCount = 1, expiresAfter = 1h) <| StormEvents | take 100
```

As expected, the following returns 100:

[Run query](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/https%3a%2f%2fhelp.kusto.windows.net/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAEACsuyS9KTYkvLE0tqowvSi0uzSnRUCrJLVDSVKhRSM4vzSsBAC0hsE4iAAAA)

```
stored_query_result("tmp") | count
```

| Count |
| --- |
| 100 |

Also as expected, this returns two rows that add up to 100:

[Run query](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/https%3a%2f%2fhelp.kusto.windows.net/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAEACsuyS9KTYkvLE0tqowvSi0uzSnRUCrJLVDSVKhRKC7NzU0syqxKVUjOL80r0dBUSKpUiPdILHbJLEpNLvHMyyotykwtVrBVgDEhEgp2CgYAEOw3KlkAAAA%3d)

```
stored_query_result("tmp")
| summarize count() by _HasDirectInjuries = InjuriesDirect > 0
```

| _HasDirectInjuries | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| False | 98 |
| True | 2 |

But unexpectedly, this always returns 0:

[Run query](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/https%3a%2f%2fhelp.kusto.windows.net/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAEACsuyS9KTYkvLE0tqowvSi0uzSnRUCrJLVDSVKhRKC7NzU0syqxKVUjOL80r0dAEAN%2bXuXEuAAAA)

```
stored_query_result("tmp") | summarize count()
```

| count_ |
| --- |
| 0 |

Why doesn't `summarize count()` work on an stored query result, when `count` and `summarize count() by ...` seem to work normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug related to stored query results, we are fixing it. Thank you very much for reporting it!